# How to fetch a dataframe with the most frequent value?

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas dataframe:

```
Player_name  Age  Calender_Year  Runs
Sid          21   2016           800
Harsh        22   2016           900        
Sid          22   2017           850
Ravi         20   2017           910    
Sumit        20   2016           760
Sumit        21   2017           690
Raj          19   2016           1100
Sid          20   2015           550
Raj          20   2017           770
```

I am looking to get result based on Player_name which is repeated the most number of times.
Output should be as below (in dataframe format):

```
Player_name  Age  Calender_Year  Runs
Sid          21   2016           800
Sid          22   2017           850
Sid          20   2015           550
```

Can anyone help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get top value by [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) with select first index and then filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) or [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
a = df.Player_name.value_counts().index[0]
print (a)
Sid

df = df[df.Player_name == a]
#alternative
#df = df.query('Player_name == @a')
print (df)
  Player_name  Age  Calender_Year  Runs
0         Sid   21           2016   800
2         Sid   22           2017   850
7         Sid   20           2015   550
```